# Async Client Server System.Net.Sockets.SocketException After First Run

Tags: c#, asynchronous, client-server

I have a async client-server in which data is sent back and forth. The sequence completes successfully and closes the socket connection appropriately the first time. On the click of a button, the same sequence should occur. However, there is sometimes a SocketException that occurs when the client tries to send data to the server after the first run.

Am I doing something wrong with establishing the connection, is it timing related, or is there something else that I am missing that would cause the error?

I added the _baseSocket.Poll() in an attempt to fix this issue. It did improve performance, but I still do get a crash error eventually as a repeat the process, mainly when I am too quick to click the button to restart the process. If I have a breakpoint, it works everytime. I have tried adding some timing delays, but that has not resolved this issue either.

Main WPF Form

```
private void connectCallback(object sender, string error)
{
    if(!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new ConnectCallback(connectCallback), sender, 
            error);
        return;
    }
}
```

OtherClass

```
public void Connect(string hostName, int port, ConnectCallback callback)
{
    _connectCallback = callback;
    _baseSocket.BeginConnect(hostName, port, connectCallback, null);
}

private void connectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    string error = null;
    try
    {
        _baseSocket.EndConnect(ar);
        EndPoint = (IPEndPoint)_baseSocket.RemoteEndPoint;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        error = ex.Message;
    }

    _connectCallback(this, error);
}


public void Send(string data, int bufferSize)
{
    byte[] bData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    byte[] sendBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    bData.CopyTo(sendBuffer, 0);


    _baseSocket.Poll(10, SelectMode.SelectWrite);
    _baseSocket.sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new 
        AsyncCallback(SendCallback), _baseSocket);
}
```